# Windows phone embedded 8 DeviceCapability PointofService causes error on deploy

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, barcode-scanner, windows-embedded-8

I added this line

```
 <DeviceCapability Name="PointOfService"/>
```

to my Package.appxmanifest, in order to use the scanner of a windows phone 8 embedded device. After adding the mentioned line, launching the project fails with this error:

> Package could not be registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF6)

Can someone tell me the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar problem on a Windows Embedded 8.1 Handheld device. In order to to enable the bar code scanner replace the current device capability with this.

```
    <DeviceCapability Name="C243FFBD-3AFC-45E9-B3D3-2BA18BC7EBC5"/>
```

This is actually mentioned in the article on MSDN for how to create a bar code scanner application, which can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792060%28v=winembedded.81%29.aspx), but it isn't overly obvious.

After doing that the application should deploy. If you still have problems with it not scanning bar codes then try setting the bar code symbologies for the ClaimedBarcodeScanner after you've claimed it to the bar code types you want it to scan. For example the following enables the GS1 128 bar code symbology:

```
await claimedScanner.SetActiveSymbologiesAsync(new List<uint> {BarcodeSymbologies.Gs1128});
```

Everything else you need to know about how to get the data from the bar code scanner can be found in the afore mentioned article.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with your DeviceCapability the project can be started and after setting the Symbologies even scanning is working